# What string format pattern for 0,"0.E+00" double value

Tags: c#, string-formatting

```
double value = 0.0
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(""));
```

Apply what string format pattern to be able to get this result: 0.E+00

I apply this pattern: #.########E+00 and the dot was missing from the result

Comment: You are going to have to insert that '.' yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[Double.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
double value =0.0;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("E1"));
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.0E+00"))
```

> ```
> 0.0E+000
> 0.0E+00
> ```

You did mean 0.0E correct? I'm not good at this but I don't think 0.E is valid scientific notation...